# how to put one of the values in a stream in a String

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an int type number. If the number is 0, then put "bad" in the String, If the number is 1, then put "normal" in the String, If the number is 2, then put "good" in the String. Is it possible to do this in stream?

```java
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(3); // 0 - bad  1 - normal  2 - good
String str = IntStream.of(x).
```

Comment: It's not clear what IntStream has to do with this. You have *single* value... how are streams involved? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to map a single value to a string label.
You could define a hashmap to map integer values to their labels for this purpose.

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "bad");
map.put(1, "normal");
map.put(2, "good");
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(3); // 0 - bad  1 - normal  2 - good
String str = map.get(x);
```

If you had a *collection* of integer values, then using a stream might make more sense:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
List<String> labels = list.stream()
                          .map(x -> map.get(x))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(labels);  // [bad, normal, good]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.
You can use the `IntStream#mapToObj` method.

However, there are better ways of doing so. But as you're asking to do it with a `Stream`, here it is.

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(3); // 0 - bad  1 - normal  2 - good
String str = IntStream.of(x).mapToObj($ ->
        switch ($) {
            case 0 -> "bad";
            case 1 -> "normal";
            case 2 -> "good";
            default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + x);
        }
).findFirst().orElseThrow();

System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

Comment: How do you know what Java version is used by OP?

Comment: yes. thanks. I want to study the streams better now. therefore, sometimes there are questions, they may be inefficient work, but I will understand the work of the stream

Comment: I don't, I just use the latest LTS @MissChanandlerBong

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a const-like Map to store your mappings between strings and integers.
Then you can use `mapToObj` function to get result using Java streams.

For a single element, that might look like

```
Map<Integer, String> mapping = Map.of(0, "bad", 1, "normal", 2, "good");
String result = IntStream.of(2).mapToObj(mapping::get).findFirst().get();
```

For multiple elements:
For a single element, that might look like

```
Map<Integer, String> mapping = Map.of(0, "bad", 1, "normal", 2, "good");
List<String> results = IntStream.of(2).mapToObj(mapping::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```